# Renting building from a church

Tags: money, transactions, christianity, real-estate, rental

[The question of renting a hall in a Church to use for a simcha (bar mitzvah) has been discussed.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/renting-a-simcha-hall-from-a-church) I have a similar question, however a little different.

There is a Christian church that owns a large building. Part of it is used for their worship and other activities. However, another part of the building (which is essentially separate) is rented or given out to other organizations/people to use. For a while a Jewish school was using one of the rooms for a play group of young children. They were given this room for free and had no problem going into this part of the building since it was separate from the Church and used for many other things. However, now the Church wants to charge rent, and seemingly the money would be going to the Church.

Is there anything wrong with this?

Is this perhaps the same exact case as the one above? The reason it might be different is that, although connected to the church, the room's not literally part of the Church's building, to the extent that to walk into it was no problem. Perhaps the money being paid for the rent can be looked at as if it's going for the building up-keep (and what the Church ultimately decides to do with it wouldn't matter). Many times people might do business with gentiles and the money could go to their causes. Perhaps could rely on the Poskim that Christianity is not Avodah Zarah and therefore not a problem at all (there is much from the Meiri in what he wrote on Shas and in Teshuvas about this topic -- he is quite makil).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if it's on the premesis or not, it depends on if the money will be used to enhance/repair/beautify Avodah Zoro or just to the people.

When they were using it for free it was no problem but when paying rent it would depend on the above and on the issue of wanting the Avodah Zoro to remain standing. See Shulchan Aruch Yore Dei'ah 143:3 and the Darkei Teshuvah there, also see 148:12.

But asking a rabbi is a must.