# 12-step recovery programs with Gentiles

Tags: halacha, gentiles, medicine, tzibur-community, liquor-beer

Based on well-known results, 12-step programs based on Alcoholics Anonymous and branching out to narcotics and such, appear to be extremely effective.   However, since Jews are roughly a 1:100 minority in most of the United States (densely populated cities being an exception, of course), it's unlikely a Jewish alcoholic will be able to find a fully Jewish AA group.

Since AA requires surrender of control of our lives to "G-d as we understand Him", as one of the steps, religiously there should be no problem with a Jew's joining a non-fully-Jewish AA group.

Moreover, because one of the main rules in AA is to never encounter fellow members socially, there should be no danger of intermarriage from this.  Am I right?

Is there anything else I should be concerned with when deciding to join such a group?

Comment: many meetings are held in churches, which may be a problem. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3666/voting-in-a-church and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/renting-a-simcha-hall-from-a-church and linked questions

Comment: This article seems to imply that one can attend an AA meeting as long as this doesn't lead to participation in non-Jewish communal prayer (and it even endorses the communal recitation with non-Jews of Tehillim in English!): http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/848875/jewish/Is-the-Lords-Prayer-Non-denominational.htm

Comment: If you need a 12-step program, it's mamish pikuach nefesh.

Comment: Rabbi Shais Taub in [his book](http://www.amazon.com/God-Our-Understanding-Spirituality-Addiction/dp/1602801533) has an appendix which provides 12 step programs to contact which are appropriate for Torah observant Jews. I don't have the book to check if he specifically lists issues to look out for, but I think it would be a good resource for your question.

Comment: Not that an anonymous someone on the internet matters, but I weighed these issues and in the end I accompanied a close friend to a meeting run by the Caren institute which was held in a church. I was happy when I got there that the meating was in a basement room and not the main sanctuary but I had gone fully willing to go into the sanctuary too if need be.

Answer (score 2):

Mingling with gentiles for a specific purpose that can't be accomplished with Jews is perfectly fine.

If you need the 12 step program, go for it.

However, I [can not offer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734/2) personalized, professional advice, and this website does not take the place of seeking such advice [from your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi).

Comment: I don't doubt your first sentence, but [edit]ing in a source or argument for it would make your answer *much* more valuable.